# Cannot accessed to a file that was opened and closed

Tags: c#, file

through my application, i open a text file, read it and than close it. 
then, manually accessing to that file is restricted.
how do i solve it?

here is my code:

```
fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Weather\somePlace.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,  FileShare.ReadWrite);
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fs))      
{
    String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   

    //Deserialize the json output
    var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseData);

    // do something with the information

    fs.Close();
    fs = null;
}
```

thanks !

Comment: By "manually accessing" do you mean accessing from file explorer?

Comment: 'FileAccess.ReadWrite'?

Comment: @aloisdg He only needs to read it.

Answer (score 0):

As `FileStream` is `IDisposable`, it should be disposed after usage.

So wrap it into `using` to ensure file will be released:

```
using(fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Weather\somePlace.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,  FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
   // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Not required as `StreamReader` is wrapped in `using`. That will take care of disposing the underlying stream.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Have a look into `StreamReader` source code (can be obtained by Reflector or other .NET decompilation tool). It is clearly can be seen that in `StreamReader.Dispose` stream only being closed and `Dispose` is not called for stream.

Comment: Yes, very correct. It calls `Close` and did you checked what does that `Close` does? It calls `Dispose(true)` right away. So, your answer isn't any helpful IMHO.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Oh, you're right. I missed the fact of `Stream` disposing on `Close`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the FileStream actually. You can just use this:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Weather\somePlace.json"))      
{
    String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   

    //Deserialize the json output
    var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseData);

    // do something with the information
}
```